# How to get a row position using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a leaderboard which shows the top people who have had the most sales.

It's simple. It just gets the top 25 and displays them

```
$user = \App\User::orderBy('sales', 'desc')
        ->take(25)
        ->get();
```

So that could end up with

```
+-------+-------------------+
|  pos  |user_id|   sales   |
----------------------------|
| 1     |    1  | 1,293     |
| 2     |   99  | 1,093     |
| 3     |   45  | 985       |
| 4     |  948  | 900       |
| 5     |   39  | 889       |
| 6     |   29  | 887       |
+---------------------------+
```

Now how can I get the position of the user who is viewing the leaderboard if they are not in the top 25?

If the user id 219 is at the position 935 I want to display something like this at the end

```
+-------+-------------------+
|  pos  |user_id|   sales   |
|---------------------------|
| 935   |  219  |     87    |
+---------------------------+
```

How is this possible to do efficiently without counting up to the user? (As there are thousands of users)

Comment: $user = \App\User::find($userId, ['pos']);
$pos = $user->pos;

Comment: @Davit `pos` is not a field in db.

Comment: Yep `pos` isn't a field. I'm just counting the top 25 in a loop.

Comment: you can see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/1895127#1895127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/1895127#1895127)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have current user data. So, you don't have to query database to get current user `id` or `sales`. So, the main problem is to find **count of users** who have more `sales` than current.

So, you need a query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as pos FROM your_table WHERE sales > %current_user_sales%
```

Translate it to laravel query and add `1` when ouptutting.

Comment: Wow, both simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: Tested in mysql - you can use `COUNT() + 1` in a query.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not my exact issue but this totally simplified it and gave me the solution. BRAVO!